# Is there a way to fix this error while using Tiktok oauth2?

Tags: node.js, tiktok

when i try to use tiktok oauth2 for my app it says a error about the redirect uri

"We couldn't log in with TikTok. This may be due to specific app settings.

If you're a developer, correct the following and try again:

redirect_uri
Refer to our Developer Documentation for more information."

fix the url. still happens. im a newbie to tiktok devs.
i checked and it still was there, fixed it.
im using replit for the code

Comment: facing same issue